# Storing data received via MQTT from ESP32 in a Python Database

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am working on monitoring the electric conssumption of a machine. I do it with Circuit Setup SSP Energy Meter (which includes an ESP32 and an ATM90E32) sampling every 50ms. I am sending data via MQTT to a Raspberry Pi, but now I have to store that data for further analysis, for what I am using a Python script. I am reading the data perfectly in the suscriptor (the Raspberry) but i just can't figure out how to store it properly.

This is the ESP32 code:

```
#define ESP32

#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ATM90E32.h>

unsigned long tiempo;
float Ts = 0.05;

const char* ssid = "xxx"; 
const char* password =  "xxx";

const char* mqttServer = "192.168.0.xxx";
const int mqttPort = 1883;
const char* mqttUser = "xxx";
const char* mqttPassword = "xxx";
const char* HATopic = "home/energy/sensor";

unsigned short lineFreq = 389;             
unsigned short PGAGain = 21;   
unsigned short VoltageGain = 7908;
unsigned short CurrentGainCT1 = 39473;
unsigned short CurrentGainCT2 = 39473;
const int CS_pin = 5; 

ATM90E32 eic{}; 

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
  delay(2000);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Conectando a WiFi...");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Conectado a Wifi con éxito");

  client.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
 
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Conectando a MQTT...");
 
    if (client.connect("EnergyMeterClient", mqttUser, mqttPassword )) {
 
      Serial.println("Conectado");
 
    } else {
 
      Serial.print("Fallo con estado ");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      delay(2000);
 
    }
  }
 
  Serial.println("Iniciar ATM90E32");
  eic.begin(CS_pin, lineFreq, PGAGain, VoltageGain, CurrentGainCT1, 0, CurrentGainCT2);
  delay(1000);
  
} 
 
void loop() {

  StaticJsonDocument<256> meterData;
 
  float voltageA, voltageC, totalVoltage, currentCT1, currentCT2, totalCurrent, activePower, powerFactor, temp, freq, totalWatts;

  unsigned short sys0 = eic.GetSysStatus0(); //EMMState0
  unsigned short sys1 = eic.GetSysStatus1(); //EMMState1
  unsigned short en0 = eic.GetMeterStatus0();//EMMIntState0
  unsigned short en1 = eic.GetMeterStatus1();//EMMIntState1

  Serial.println("Sys Status: S0:0x" + String(sys0, HEX) + " S1:0x" + String(sys1, HEX));
  Serial.println("Meter Status: E0:0x" + String(en0, HEX) + " E1:0x" + String(en1, HEX));
  delay(10);

  if (sys0 == 65535 || sys0 == 0) Serial.println("Error: No se reciben datos del energy meter - comprueba el conexionado");

if ((millis()-tiempo)>(Ts)){
  
  voltageA = eic.GetLineVoltageA();
  voltageC = eic.GetLineVoltageC();
  totalVoltage = voltageA;     

  currentCT1 = eic.GetLineCurrentA();
  currentCT2 = eic.GetLineCurrentC();
  totalCurrent = currentCT1 + currentCT2;

  activePower = eic.GetTotalActivePower();
  powerFactor = eic.GetTotalPowerFactor();
  //temp = eic.GetTemperature();
  //freq = eic.GetFrequency();
  //totalWatts = (voltageA * currentCT1) + (voltageC * currentCT2);
}

/*
  Serial.println("Voltage 1: " + String(voltageA) + "V");
  Serial.println("Voltage 2: " + String(voltageC) + "V");
  Serial.println("Current 1: " + String(currentCT1) + "A");
  Serial.println("Current 2: " + String(currentCT2) + "A");
  Serial.println("Active Power: " + String(realPower) + "W");
  Serial.println("Power Factor: " + String(powerFactor));
  Serial.println("Fundimental Power: " + String(eic.GetTotalActiveFundPower()) + "W");
  Serial.println("Harmonic Power: " + String(eic.GetTotalActiveHarPower()) + "W");
  Serial.println("Reactive Power: " + String(eic.GetTotalReactivePower()) + "var");
  Serial.println("Apparent Power: " + String(eic.GetTotalApparentPower()) + "VA");
  Serial.println("Phase Angle A: " + String(eic.GetPhaseA()));
  Serial.println("Chip Temp: " + String(temp) + "C");
  Serial.println("Frequency: " + String(freq) + "Hz");
*/

  meterData["V1"] = voltageA;
  //meterData["V2"] = voltageC;
  meterData["I1"] = currentCT1;
  //meterData["I2"] = currentCT2;
  //meterData["totI"] = totalCurrent;
  meterData["AP"] = activePower;
  meterData["PF"] = powerFactor;
  //meterData["t"] = temp;
  //meterData["f"] = freq;
  
  char JSONmessageBuffer[200];
  serializeJson(meterData,JSONmessageBuffer);
  Serial.println("Enviando mensaje al topic MQTT...");
  Serial.println(JSONmessageBuffer);

  if (client.publish(HATopic, JSONmessageBuffer) == true) {
    Serial.println("Éxito enviando mensaje");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error enviando mensaje");
  }
 
  client.loop();
  Serial.println("-------------");
  
  tiempo = millis();
 
}
```

This is what I read in the suscriptor:

[image]

This is the Python code (I found it on the internet and modified it) but I want to store the data in diferent columns ( Voltage - Current - Power - PowerFactor ) and also add a fifth one with the date and I don't really know how to do it. It's my first time working with both Python and SQL.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sqlite3
from time import time
 
MQTT_HOST = '192.168.0.xxx'
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = 'Python MQTT client'
MQTT_USER = 'xxx'
MQTT_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
TOPIC = 'home/energy/sensor'
 
DATABASE_FILE = 'mqtt.db'
 
 
def on_connect(mqtt_client, user_data, flags, conn_result):
    mqtt_client.subscribe(TOPIC)
 
 
def on_message(mqtt_client, user_data, message):
    payload = message.payload.decode('utf-8')
 
    db_conn = user_data['db_conn']
    sql = 'INSERT INTO datos_electricos (topic, payload, fecha) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, (message.topic, payload, int(time())))
    db_conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
 
 
def main():
    db_conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    sql = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datos_electricos (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        topic TEXT NOT NULL,
        payload TEXT NOT NULL,
        fecha TEXT NOT NULL
    )
    """
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.close()
 
    mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(MQTT_CLIENT_ID)
    mqtt_client.username_pw_set(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD)
    mqtt_client.user_data_set({'db_conn': db_conn})
 
    mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
    mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
 
    mqtt_client.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT)
    mqtt_client.loop_forever()
 
 
main()
```

This is the database I managed to create (This data is just raw data, I am not measuring anything right now, just doing a quick test) but as I said I would like to know how to separate data from the JSON buffer into different columns and also how to store a proper datetime format:

[image: image2]

Thank you very much for your help and your time.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, the first one is impossible to read. Always post the text if possible and use the options to format it.

Comment: OK, so you can store the whole message in the database, good start. You now need to break this down into smaller problems. First, how do you parse the JSON into a data structure you can extract the values from. Second how do you create a different database schema that has the columns you want. Then thirdly how to insert the values. Go and research each of the separate task and try. When you get stuck you can come back and show what you've tried and how it didn't work and we'll help you fix it, but as it this question is too broad.

Comment: Try decoding the payload with json loads, you are currently just reading it as a raw string.

Answer (score 1):

Using Json.loads() worked for me. Thanks. This is the code btw (Now I just need to figure how to add a proper datetime and if I should do it on the ESP32 or when storing the data in SQLite)

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sqlite3
import json
from time import time
 
MQTT_HOST = '192.168.0.xxx'
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = 'Python MQTT client'
MQTT_USER = 'xxx'
MQTT_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
TOPIC = 'home/energy/sensor'
 
DATABASE_FILE = 'mqtt.db'
 
 
def on_connect(mqtt_client, user_data, flags, conn_result):
    mqtt_client.subscribe(TOPIC)
 
 
def on_message(mqtt_client, user_data, message):
    payload = message.payload.decode('utf-8')
    variables=json.loads(payload)
    
    V=str(variables["V1"])
    I=str(variables["I1"])
    AP=str(variables["AP"])
    PF=str(variables["PF"])
    
    db_conn = user_data['db_conn'] #Conexion
    cursor = db_conn.cursor() #Inicio cursor
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO datos_electricos (tension,intensidad,potencia,factor) VALUES (" + V + "," + I + "," + AP + "," + PF + ")")
    db_conn.commit() #Envio de la instruccion SQL
    cursor.close() #Cierre cursor
 
def main():
    db_conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    sql = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datos_electricos (   
        tension FLOAT,
        intensidad FLOAT,
        potencia FLOAT,
        factor FLOAT
    )
    """
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.close()
 
    mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(MQTT_CLIENT_ID)
    mqtt_client.username_pw_set(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD)
    mqtt_client.user_data_set({'db_conn': db_conn})
 
    mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
    mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
 
    mqtt_client.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT)
    mqtt_client.loop_forever()
 
 
main()
```